# question on vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

if $W_1,W_2,W_3$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $W_3$ is contained in $W_1$.then which of the followings are true:

a) $W_1 \cap (W_2 + W_3) = W_2 + W_1 \cap W_3.$

b) $W_1 \cap (W_2 + W_3) = W_3 + (W_1 \cap W_2).$

c) $W_1 \cup (W_2 + W_3) = W_2 + W_1 \cup W_3.$

d) none of these.

I tried and found that option b is true can someone tell me about other options. I also want to ask if intersection and addition of subspaces are given together then what should be taken first i.e. what is meant by $W_2 + W_1 \cup W_3$?

Comment: If you have typed out in latex, why not just put a few dollar signs?

Comment: i cannot understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: He's saying that instead of writing \bigcap you should write \$ \bigcap \$, for instance. You should only use \$ \bigcap \$ if you want to put a subscript such as $\bigcap_{y \in X}$ underneath it. Otherwise you should use \$ \cap \$.

Comment: [please someone help me

Comment: @user93233 I'm not aware of any standard order of operations to clarify the right hand side of the first or last expression. One might guess that the addition comes last.

Comment: can someone help me in solving this question

Answer (score 0):

In the second case we have:
\begin{align*}
W_1 \cap (W_2+W_3) &= (W_1 \cap W_2)+(W_1 \cap W_3) & \text{distributivity} \\
 &=(W_1 \cap W_3)+(W_1 \cap W_2) & \text{commutativity} \\
 &=W_1+(W_1 \cap W_2) & \text{by assumption } W_3 \subseteq W_1. \\
\end{align*}
So, the second case is always true.

Now, the first and third cases can be true for some $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ satisfying the conditions, so presumably the task is to show that they're not always true.

We can eliminate the first case by choosing subspaces of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $|W_1|=|W_3|=1$ and $|W_2|=2$, say.  This implies $$|W_1 \cap (W_2+W_3)|=1$$ and $$|W_2+(W_1 \cap W_3)|=2$$ which would not be true if the first statement were true in general.

We can eliminate the third case by choosing subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|W_3|=1$, $W_1=\mathrm{span}((0,1))$ and $W_2=\mathrm{span}((1,0))$.  In this situation the identity $$W_1 \cup (W_2+W_3)=W_2+(W_1 \cup W_3)$$ is equivalent to $$W_1 \cup W_2=W_2+W_1$$ which is not true for this example: $(1,1) \in W_2+W_1$, whereas $(1,1) \not\in W_1 \cup W_2$.

Comment: hello rebecca can you tell me first we solve intersection or sum

Comment: I would guess $A+B \cap C=A+(B \cap C)$.  But I would argue that $A+B \cap C$ is ill-defined, and it's better to use brackets.  (Actually, I noticed I wrote that once; I'll change it.)